# "That's too useful" - What does this mean? Where did it come from?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I've heard in casual speak some people say "Oh, that's too useful, no wonder they don't want that out there!" or something similar along those lines (several unrelated people in independent events).  For example, in reference to homebrew/unofficial documentation about a piece of software.

What does this saying really mean?  How did it come to be?

It seems counter intuitive and/or Yogi Berra-esque.

This may be a US-only thing and/or may be just a technology thing.

Comment: It is used ironically: This is good (useful). They don't want good things to be out there (e.g. known about). So it is no wonder that they don't advertise this.

Comment: I picked up on the irony, and brushed off the first person saying it.  However, it's happened multiple times.  Maybe it's kind of like a back handed compliment?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about conspiracy theorist culture, not the use of English

Comment: In a (very) few contexts, "too" is used idiomatically to mean "very". The only other example I can think of off-hand is "too cute", but there are probably others.

Comment: I think you mean *Yogi Berra*---or were you referring to the the cartoon character *Yogi Bear*?

Comment: Compare to the expression "too obvious".  The meaning is that something is so obvious that it's overlooked.  "Too useful" has something of the same sense, though it's often used, eg, to describe something that a big corporation overlooks (either intentionally or through incompetence).

Comment: @DavidHandelman -- You think someone made a Boo Boo?

Comment: Idk what all the hate is about.  The question's been upvoted a good bit, and as far as I can tell, fits the idea of the site, specifically #1 and #3. (re: help center)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Drew's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/355676/thats-too-useful-what-does-this-mean-where-did-it-come-from#comment825472_355676) points in the general direction, and [your response](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/355676/thats-too-useful-what-does-this-mean-where-did-it-come-from#comment825476_355676) is also apt, so I'll use that context for the following example.

In code/IT, as well as other technical pursuits, it can be the case that the people who develop or sell some item (let's call them *ABC*) also service (or *support*) that item. For various reasons, ABC may not want *end users* (also *endusers* in US) to actually try to service the item themselves. (Reasons may include

- ABC wants to be paid to service the item.
- ABC fears getting sued by end users who injure themselves attempting to service the item.

and may be multiply applicable.) If so, ABC will not want information that *could* assist (or be useful for) some enduser to reach them. More generally, when person P says that something is "too useful," typically

1. that something is information
2. P means that the information would actually be useful to some person/group Q to perform some activity A
3. P means that some person/group R does not anyone else (at least, not Q) to perform A, and therefore does not want that information to reach Q
4. P might more exactly/tediously say that "R fears that information would allow Q to do A," but as noted above, persons who use "too useful" typically intend to be droll.

Comment: Idk why you got negs. Pretty sure this is spot on and at least part of what's going on.

Comment: +1 for your answer. Well, probably you can add some external sources to back up your claim. And just a trivia, I thought you write 'endusers' wrongly (I read it 'endorsers' initially, but it's not) - end-users probably or end users to make it more readable a bit.